# Where do I need to place my Django tests so that they get executed?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I would like to create and run some unit tests.  Per the Django documentation, I created this file ...

```
ls ./mainpage/tests/test_models.py
```

But when I run my tests using the command below, it says zero tests were executed ...

```
(venv) localhost:mainpage_project davea$ cd /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project; source ./venv/bin/activate; python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Article.main_page_first_appeared_date received a naive datetime (2019-01-29 22:43:53.575128) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Below are the contents of my file.  What am I missing?  Where should I put my tests or how should they be named so that they get executed?

```
from django.test import TestCase
from mainpage.models import ArticleStat, Article


class TestModels(unittest.TestCase):

    # Test saving an article stat that hasn't previously
    # existed
    def test_add_articlestat(self):
        id = 1
        article = Article.objects.filter(id=id)
        self.assertTrue(article, "A pre-condition of this test is that an article exist with id=" + str(id))
        articlestat = ArticleStat(article=article,elapsed_time_in_seconds=250,votes=25,comments=15)
        articlestat.save()
        article_stat = ArticleStat.objects.get(article=article)
        self.assertTrue(article_stat, "Failed to svae article stat properly.")
```

Comment: Each app has a `tests.py`, place your test code in there

Comment: don't forget to add __init__.py in your tests directory

Comment: @yorodm, People place there entire test suite in one file?  What if people want to break up tests for readability and group similar ones into different files?  Still learning Django/Python so maybe what I'm asking is not what's done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to manage tests in one directory. Like this.

```
.
├── app1
├── app2
├── ...
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_1.py
└── manage.py
```

You have to import your test classes.

```
# tests/__init__.py
from .test_1 import YourTestClass
```

Then, you can run test by `python manage.py test tests`. If you want to run only `test_1` module, command is `python manage.py test tests.test_1`